add_xy_position in rstatix doesn't work for two-way ANOVA | tukey_hsd() | Error in `group_by()`:
I'm trying to perform Two-Way ANOVA statistical tests on my data and use the add_xy_position() on the test result in order to later visualize the p-values using ggplot similarly to: https://www.datanovia.com/en/blog/how-to-add-p-values-to-ggplot-facets/
Here's my example:
library(rstatix)
library(tidyr)

#Create the Data

ID <- 1:40 #Different Individuals (i.e. Test Subjects)
Time <- c(rep('d24h', 20), rep('d48h', 20)) #Time of Sampling (unpaired), Strings are intended here for later visualization
Group <- c(rep('A', 5), rep('B', 5), rep('A', 5), rep('B', 5)) #Groups
Val <- runif(40) #Readout


df <- data.frame(ID, Time, Group, Val)

It works when performing the test for one categorical variable:
test1 <- df %>% tukey_hsd(Val~Group) %>% add_xy_position()
test1

# A tibble: 1 x 13
  term  group1 group2 null.value estimate conf.low conf.high p.adj p.adj.signif y.position groups        xmin  xmax
  <chr> <chr>  <chr>       <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl> <chr>             <dbl> <named list> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Group A      B               0    0.106  -0.0755     0.288 0.244 ns                0.968 <chr [2]>        1     2

However, when trying to perform the same for two categoricals, the following occurs:
test2 <- df %>% tukey_hsd(Val~Group*Time) %>% add_xy_position()
test2

Error in `group_by()`:
!Â Must group by variables found in `.data`.
xÂ Column `Group:Time` is not found.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.


I tried to find solutions to the problem here on stack overflow but this issue seems to be unique to my case. I expected to get y positions to the results of the tukeyHSD test.

You can't do this easily with interactions (see below for why). What you may want is to group by Time before calling tukey_hsd:
test2 <- df %>%
  group_by(Time) %>%
  tukey_hsd(Val~Group) %>% 
  add_xy_position()


test2

# A tibble: 2 × 14
  Time  term  group1 group2 null.value estimate conf.low conf.high p.adj p.adj.signif y.position groups        xmin  xmax
  <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr>       <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl> <chr>             <dbl> <named list> <dbl> <dbl>
1 d24h  Group A      B               0  -0.0786   -0.356     0.199 0.559 ns                1.02  <chr [2]>        1     2
2 d48h  Group A      B               0  -0.128    -0.369     0.114 0.282 ns                0.949 <chr [2]>        1     2

This creates a data frame containing the two comparisons you want to visualise.
ggboxplot(df, x = "Group", y = "Val", facet.by="Time") +
  stat_pvalue_manual(test2, label = "p.adj", size = 3, tip.length = 0.01) 



With interactions, it's difficult for R to know which comparisons you want.
aov(Val~Group*Time, data=df) %>%
  tukey_hsd()


# A tibble: 8 × 9
  term       group1 group2 null.value estimate conf.low conf.high p.adj p.adj.signif
* <chr>      <chr>  <chr>       <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl> <chr>       
1 Group      A      B               0  -0.103    -0.281    0.0744 0.246 ns          
2 Time       d24h   d48h            0  -0.123    -0.301    0.0541 0.167 ns          
3 Group:Time A:d24h B:d24h          0  -0.0786   -0.412    0.255  0.92  ns          
4 Group:Time A:d24h A:d48h          0  -0.0988   -0.432    0.235  0.855 ns          
5 Group:Time A:d24h B:d48h          0  -0.226    -0.560    0.107  0.276 ns          
6 Group:Time B:d24h A:d48h          0  -0.0202   -0.354    0.313  0.998 ns          
7 Group:Time B:d24h B:d48h          0  -0.148    -0.481    0.185  0.634 ns          
8 Group:Time A:d48h B:d48h          0  -0.128    -0.461    0.206  0.732 ns

There are simply too many to show on one facetted boxplot. The first two are not needed as these are the main effects. The next six are the ones you want, but the ones you want to show on the plot depend on which variable you facetted by. For the above boxplot, comparing A with B and facetted by Time, you want the p-values in the 3rd and 8th rows.

Hi Edward, I very much appreciate your comment. I'm afraid that my question lacked some additional information. The way you did the test only considered "within" time comparisons for each group. However, I intend to test the difference for each group between time points (i.e. Group A @ 24h vs. Group A @ 48h), thereby ignoring test results for other comparisons that don't have purpose (i.e. Group A @ 24h vs. Group B @ 48h), while keeping the adjusted p-Values.

For example, I'd like to have a layout for my plot that is generated as follows:
test2 <- df %>%
group_by(Time) %>%
tukey_hsd(Val ~ Group) %>%
add_xy_position(x = 'Time', dodge = .6)
ggplot(df, aes(Time, Val)) +
geom_boxplot(aes(fill = Group), position = position_dodge(.6)) +
stat_pvalue_manual(test2, label = 'p.adj')
This, however, still lacks the desired comparisons.
There is, of course, this tutorial: https://www.datanovia.com/en/blog/how-to-add-p-values-onto-a-grouped-ggplot-using-the-ggpubr-r-package/
Two tests are used (i) for Group and (ii) for Time
